# Is there a way to have a Qt QProgressBar that shows a percentage over 100% without needing to use a label?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I could use a label to do it, but I was wondering if there was a simpler way.

I already make the color of the progress bar red when it exceeds 100% of the value I'm comparing it to and green again when the value is below that, but the bar itself won't show any number larger than 100%.

For example if a is 40 and b is 80, b is 200% of a, so the progress bar should display the number 200%.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the number format from percent of total to a value, leaving the '%' as a suffix:

```
QProgressBar *progressBar = new QProgressBar;
progressBar->setRange(0, 200);
progressBar->setFormat("%v%");
progressBar->setValue(150);
```

This should display "150%" next to the progress bar.